# How to convert a sequence of strings present in tuples to a single string

Tags: python, string

I have a list of tuples:

```
x = [("initial deposit", 1000.00), ("restaurant and more foo", -15.89)]
```

How do I get a single string by converting each of the individual tuples into a string and adding the individual strings of the tuples together?

What I mean is that I want the following printed, but it has to be a single string. So, my command will be this:

```
print(single_string)
```

and the following will be printed:

```
initial deposit        1000.00
restaurant and more foo -15.89
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What did you try? And why is it important that it be formatted to a single string before printing? And why are you convinced that this way is more "scalable"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This scales linearly with the number of tuples in the `x` list:

```
x = [("initial deposit", 1000.00), ("restaurant and more foo", -15.89)]
s = ''
for e in x:
    s += e[0] + '\t' + str(e[1]) + '\n'
print(s)
```

Output:

```
initial deposit 1000.0
restaurant and more foo -15.89
```

Note the tab character `\t` and end-of-line character `\n`.